# Google Sheet search multiple values

Tags: search, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a google sheet question

I have search data as follows

```
X |  Y
1 | abc
2 | def
3 | xyz
```

I have a row of data as follows

```
A | B | C
1 | 2 | 3
```

Now I need to search data in columns A , B and C with search data table above ( column X and Y) and then have a cell filled with value

```
abc,def,xyz
```

How can I do this in Google sheet?

Comment: use LOOCKUP() or VLOOCKUP()

Comment: @AkshinJalilov - you must have meant using `LOOKUP` and `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 2):

This formula may work:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(ABCrange,XYrange,2,0))`

Here is an example sheet: https://goo.gl/5OC0gE

It is possible to automate the ABCrange on this sheet using the formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(FILTER(D1:1,LEN(D1:1)),A:B,2,0))`

Comment: If you want to have results in the same cell you might also use this: `=JOIN(",",ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(A1:C1,X1:Y3,2,0)))`